# Keras TimeDistributed layer with multiple inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I'm trying to make the following lines of code working:

```
low_encoder_out = TimeDistributed( AutoregressiveDecoder(...) )([X_tf, embeddings])
```

Where `AutoregressiveDecoder` is a custom layer that takes two inputs.
After a bit of googling, the problem seems to be that the `TimeDistributed` wrapper doesn't accept multiple inputs. There are solutions that proposes to merge the two inputs before feeding it to the layer, but since their shape is

```
X_tf.shape: (?, 16, 16, 128, 5)
embeddings.shape: (?, 16, 1024)
```

I really don't know how to merge them. Is there a way of having the `TimeDistributed` layer to work with more than one input? Or, alternatively, is there any way to merge the two inputs in a nice way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned `TimeDistributed` layer does not support multiple inputs. One (not-very-nice) workaround, considering the fact that the number of timesteps (i.e. second axis) must be the same for all the inputs, is to reshape all of them to `(None, n_timsteps, n_featsN)`, concatenate them and then feed them as input of `TimeDistributed` layer:

```
X_tf_r = Reshape((n_timesteps, -1))(X_tf)
embeddings_r = Reshape((n_timesteps, -1))(embeddings)

concat = concatenate([X_tf_r, embeddings_r])
low_encoder_out = TimeDistributed(AutoregressiveDecoder(...))(concat)
```

Of course, you might need to modify the definition of your custom layer and separate the inputs back if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was hoping to avoid that workaround, but it seems the only way to make it work... it's very weird that TimeDistributed layers do not have the support for multiple inputs, it seems quite a common use case to me...